# Google OR-Tools: Solving an objective function containing max function of multiple variables

Tags: python, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, or-tools

I'm aiming to optimize an objective function that includes a `max` function of multiple variables. Is this possible with OR-Tools given it seems to only have linear solvers and the `max` function is nonlinear? I've seen from [this](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/) and [this](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Optimization_with_absolute_values) that it's possible to linearize constraints or objective functions, but only in the case of two variables.

```
# Build data model
data = {}
data['constraint_coeffs'] = [
    [1 for x in range(10)],
]
data['bounds'] = [100]
data['max_power'] = 500
data['demand_coeffs'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
data['energy_coeffs'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6]
data['num_vars'] = 10
data['num_constraints'] = len(data['constraint_coeffs'])

# Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

# Set variables
x = {}
for j in range(data['num_vars']):
    x[j] = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'x[%i]' % j)

# Set energy constraint
for i in range(data['num_constraints']):
    constraint_expr = [data['constraint_coeffs'][i][j] * x[j] for j in range(data['num_vars'])]
    solver.Add(sum(constraint_expr) == data['bounds'][i])

# Set max power constraints
for j in range(data['num_vars']):
    solver.Add(x[j] <= data['max_power'])
```

Here's where the problem occurs:

```
obj_expr = [data['energy_coeffs'][j] * x[j] / 60 for j in range(data['num_vars']) + max(data['demand_coeffs'][j] * x[j] for j in range(data['num_vars']))]
solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(obj_expr))

status = solver.Solve()
```

And here's the error message:

```
ValueError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-03aba3620a74> in <module>
----> 1 obj_expr = [data['energy_coeffs'][j] * x[j] / 60 for j in range(data['num_vars']) + max(data['demand_coeffs'][j] * x[j] for j in range(data['num_vars']))]

~/anaconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver_natural_api.py in __gt__(self, arg)
    152   def __gt__(self, arg):
    153     raise ValueError(
--> 154         'Operators "<" and ">" not supported with the linear solver')
    155 
    156   def __ne__(self, arg):

ValueError: Operators "<" and ">" not supported with the linear solver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in any solver.  If you want to minimize the maximum of a set of values, you can simply introduce a new dummy variable and constrain it to be greater than each of the values in the set and then use that dummy variable in your objective.  So in pseudocode:

```
Let:
c[i] = some indexed set of coefficients
x[i] = some indexed variable

Desire:
minimax (c[i]*x[i])

Introduce:
my_max = real valued variable, non-indexed

Make constraint
for i in I:
  my_max >= c[i]*x[i]
```

Then you can use `my_max` (or whatever you call it) in your objective (minimization) function instead of the `max()`

Comment: Thanks! Sounds obvious now that you mention it. One variant of this - is it possible for the solver to find the max x[i] for all i, then have the objective function be c[i] * x[i] for that index i?

Comment: That is significantly more difficult as the proposed construct is blind to the index `i` of the max.